# Soft release a product in Salesforce

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook, product

I want to add some products into another environment towards release and I want to be able to hide the product from certain users for a while. Then if everything goes well I want to make it visible to all the users.

Is this possible in Salesforce? If yes, please provide the steps in achieving this.

The goal is:

- I will be able to add product to an opportunity
- Only certain users might see this product so that they could do this
- Update product to be seen and used by all users

P.S. I am a beginner in Salesforce Integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible & it's actually quite easy. What you will need to do is create a new pricebook that you then limit access to. Make that pricebook available to the users that will need access to your new product. (If you are not already using pricebooks, you will actually need to create two new, custom pricebooks - one for general use & one for limited use - as the standard pricebook will contain all products. You should then remove access to the standard pricebook & assign one or both of the new pricebooks to your users.)

You will then need to create your new products & add them only to the limited use pricebook. This will allow only those users with access to that pricebook to add those products to opportunities. All users will be able to see these products.